Mysterious padding in ContentView of WindowScene on tvOS
I get unwanted padding around my content in a tvOS 15.0+ app.  Can anyone tell me what is causing it and how to remove it?  See image below.  The unwanted padding is yellow.
import SwiftUI
@main
struct TestTVOSWindowScenePaddingApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
//                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
//                .safeAreaPadding(.init(0))
                .background(Color.yellow)
        }
  }
}


